# Problem with babel package

Tags: babel

In the following code when I am using `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` everything works fine until I try to use `\selectlanguage{greek}` then I get that error and those warnings:

! Corrupted NFSS tables.wrong@fontshape ...message {Corrupted NFSS tables}error@fontshape else let f... \selectlanguage{greek}

Font shape `LGR/GFSArtemisia(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using`LGR/cmr/m/n' instead

Font shape `LGR/GFSArtemisia(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using`EU1/lmr/m/n' instead

Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

On the other hand when I am trying to use `\usepackage[engish,greek]{babel}` I will not even bother to mention how many problems I get!

I use XeLaTeX and Texmaker.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

This is the worst case using `\usepackage[engish,greek]{babel}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\en}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{document}

Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων που ονομάζονται
χαρακτηριστικά. Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα χαρακτηριστικών.

$\overline{x}=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\text{Feature1}\\
\text{Feature2}\\
\text{Feature2}\\
\end{array}
\right]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `fontspec` before `babel`. But I don't see any `\selectlanguage{greek}` in your example. Please, help us to help you: MWE should reproduce the error you get. This one doesn't.

Comment: Sorry I will edit my question.

Comment: `fontspec` works better with `poliglossia`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in loading `babel` before `fontspec`, which sets the document encoding to `EU1` (with XeLaTeX) or `EU2` (with LuaLaTeX). When this fact is known, `babel` is able to load the Greek language adapting it for those engines, without doing the tricks it has to do with the `LGR` encoding for `pdflatex`.

This might be improved in `babel`, but the remedy is very simple:

> load `fontspec` before `babel`

Here's a polished up version:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\begin{document}

Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων που ονομάζονται
χαρακτηριστικά. Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα χαρακτηριστικών.

$\overline{x}=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\text{Feature1}\\
\text{Feature2}\\
\text{Feature2}\\
\end{array}
\right]$

\end{document}
```

Note that `unicode-math` also loads `fontspec`; however, using Latin Modern Math with Artemisia is not really the best, in my opinion.

Also declaring Artemisia as the sans serif font is questionable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried loading `fontspec` before `babel` when I saw your comment and I had countless errors. Even your version when I compile it produces errors and warnings. I use Texmaker if this makes any different and xelatex. I will add it to my question in case it helps.

Comment: @Adam Texmaker doesn't make any difference. The TeX distribution may, if it's not up-to-date.

Comment: I downloaded it last year so I think is up-to-date.

Comment: If it's TeX Live 2013, it isn't.

Comment: I am still an amateur so what I say may be stupid but I downloaded Miktex.

Comment: Also MiKTeX needs updates. Please, ensure you have all the packages to their last release.

Comment: OK I will check it now.

Comment: I updated it and now everything run smoothly! I didn't even know that there was an upgrade manager. Thank you very much! Not only for the current answer but also for the MikTeX update.